# Использование trail Render и AddForce

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать след за 2д спрайтом.
Использую trail Render,двигаю персонажа таким кодом:

```
m_Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 100);
```

При обычном передвижение (передвигаю мышкой по сцене вручную) след есть , при `transform.position` также , но с `AddForce` нет.

Comment: Так AddForce и не двигает, а только придает импульс, который меняет скорость. Сам персонаж-то хоть двигается после этого?

Comment: @trollingchar в этом и проблема ,кроме импульса его дальше ничто не движет .

Comment: Я запутался. Персонажа двигает только импульс, или все кроме импульса?

Comment: @trollingchar только импульс.